# Loop with an array to read integers from file, sort them according to range. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement, integer

Right now Im trying to write a program that can take an input file that has a bunch of integers, and then show the amount of numbers in certain ranges. For example:

If the input file has 20, 30, 40, 50, 60. And the ranges are 1-20, 21-40, 41-60

The output would be

1-20: 1
21-40: 2
41-60: 3

etc.

Im new to programming, so Im just having a little problem with my code, I know im close. Im using arrays to store them, but I wasnt sure how to make an array that adapts to how many integers there are in a file. So this is what I got so far. (Just for this exercise, Im trying to make the max amount the array will store 100 integers).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int ranges(int);


int main()
{
ifstream indata;
ofstream outdata;

indata.open("scores1.txt");

outdata.open("scoresoutput.txt");

if(!indata)
{
    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    return 1;
}

int range1=0;
int range2=0;
int range3=0;
int range4=0;
int range5=0;
int range6=0;
int range7=0;
int range8=0;


const int max=100;
int score[max];



while(indata)
{

    for(int i=0; i < max ; i++)
    {

    indata >> score[i];
    indata.ignore(1);

    if(0 <= score[i] <= 24)
            {
            range1++;
            }

            else if(25 <= score[i] <= 49)
            {
                range2++;
            }

            else if(50 <= score[i] <=74)
            {
                range3++;
            }

            else if(75<= score[i] <= 99)
            {
                range4++;
            }

            else if(100 <= score[i] <= 124)
            {
                range5++;
            }

            else if(125 <= score[i] <= 149)
            {
                range6++;
            }

            else if(150 <= score[i] <= 174)
            {
                range7++;
            }

            else if(175 <= score[i]<= 200)
            {
                range8++;
            }


    }

        }



outdata << "Range" << setw(10) << "Number of Students" << endl <<
    "0-24" << setw(10) << range1 << endl<<
    "25-49" << setw(10) << range2 << endl <<
    "50-74" << setw(10) << range3 << endl <<
    "75-99" << setw(10) << range4 << endl <<
    "100-124" << setw(10) << range5 << endl <<
    "125-149" << setw(10) << range6 << endl <<
    "150-174" << setw(10) << range7 << endl <<
    "175-200" << setw(10) << range8 << endl;


return 0;

}
```

Right now, the output just displays 0-24      100. Any easier way to do this than what I am doing now?

Comment: It would be better to use arrays handle the ranges and use an formula to handle its upper and lower bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Array is your good friend.  Try to use an array to manage the counts:

```
int range_count[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  range_count[i] = 0;
}
```

and in the for-loop inside your while-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < max ; ++i) {

  indata >> score[i];
  indata.ignore(1);

  if (score[i] >= 0 && score[i] <= 200) {
    range_count[score[i] / 25]++; // since your range intervals is a constant 25.
  }
}
```

and finally, in the output:

```
outdata << "Range" << setw(10) << "Number of Students" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
  i * 25 << "-" << i * 25 + 24 << setw(10) << range_count[i] << endl;
}
```